# $.ajax fill changing objectname passed as function argument?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to parse several jSON files into several objects.

My approach looks as follows:

```
function download_datasave (target_object) {
//  DOWNLOAD CALCULATION BACKUP
    var filename, response
        filename = target_object.name + '.json' ;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: datasave_hostname,
        timeout : 3000 ,
        data: {
            action : "download", target : filename, data : ""
            },
        success: function (data) {
            response = JSON.parse(data) ;
            this[target_object] = response ;    // doesn´t work , results is empty object
            window[target_object] = response ;  // doesn't work , results in empty object (as its the same)
            aufloesung_history = response ; // does work, but how to solve this for more than one target_Object ??
        },
        error : function (data) { console.log(target_object.name + " : Download failed , ServerMessage : " + data); }
    });
    };
```

Please see the comments inside success. Stuff like "console.log(response)" are returning the correct Object(s) inside aufloesung_history for example.

Any thoughts?

derdigge

**EDIT**

This is how objects are created:

```
objects = [
"aufloesung", "aufloesung_history",
"grobsortierung", "grobsortierung_history",
"lcreinigung", "lcreinigung_history",
"fraktionierung", "fraktionierung_history",
"feinsortierung", "feinsortierung_history",
"eindickung", "eindickung_history"
];

function create_objects () {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        window[objects[i]] = {};
        window[objects[i]].name = objects[i] ;
    }
};
```

**EDIT2**

I commented more of the console logs inside the code look:

```
function download_datasave (target_object, target) {
    //  DOWNLOAD CALCULATION BACKUP

    var filename, response ;

    console.log(this[aufloesung_history]) ;     //undefinied

    if (!(arguments[1])) {
        filename = target_object.name + '.json' ;
    } else {
        filename = arguments[1] + '.json' ;
    }

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: datasave_hostname,
            timeout : 3000 ,
            data: {
                action : "download", target : filename, data : ""
                },
            success: function (data) {
                    response = JSON.parse(data) ;
                console.log(aufloesung_history) ;       //  empty object
                    this[target_object] = {} ;
                console.log(aufloesung_history) ;       //  empty object
                    this[target_object] = response ;
                console.log(aufloesung_history) ;       //  empty object
                    aufloesung_history = {} ;
                console.log(aufloesung_history) ;       //  empty Object
                    aufloesung_history = response ;
                console.log(aufloesung_history) ;       //  right contents inside object
                console.log(this[aufloesung_history]) ; //  right contents inside object 
                console.log(this[target_object]) ;      //  right contents inside object
            },
            error : function (data) { console.log(target_object.name + " : Download failed , ServerMessage : " + data); }
        });
};
```

The data it self look like this inside an correct object:
[correct object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqbju.jpg)

The .json is created earlier from an correct object using `JSON.stringify(target_object)` in an upload function which looks similar.

Here is one json blob:

```
{"name":"aufloesung_history","0":{"start":1446043200,"stop":1446063000,"start_h":"28.10.2015, 15:40","stop_h":"28.10.2015, 21:10","duration":19800},"1":{"start":1446153600,"stop":1446157800,"start_h":"29.10.2015, 22:20","stop_h":"29.10.2015, 23:30","duration":4200},"2":{"start":1446170400,"stop":1446173400,"start_h":"30.10.2015, 3:00","stop_h":"30.10.2015, 3:50","duration":3000},"3":{"start":1446229200,"stop":1446267000,"start_h":"30.10.2015, 19:20","stop_h":"31.10.2015, 5:50","duration":37800},"4":{"start":1446270600,"stop":1446363000,"start_h":"31.10.2015, 6:50","stop_h":"01.11.2015, 8:30","duration":92400},"5":{"start":1446366600,"stop":1446409200,"start_h":"01.11.2015, 9:30","stop_h":"01.11.2015, 21:20","duration":42600},"6":{"start":1446415200,"stop":1446421800,"start_h":"01.11.2015, 23:00","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 0:50","duration":6600},"7":{"start":1446422400,"stop":1446435000,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 1:00","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 4:30","duration":12600},"8":{"start":1446436200,"stop":1446450600,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 4:50","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 8:50","duration":14400},"9":{"start":1446452400,"stop":1446456600,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 9:20","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 10:30","duration":4200},"10":{"start":1446457200,"stop":1446464400,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 10:40","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 12:40","duration":7200},"11":{"start":1446473400,"stop":1446481800,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 15:10","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 17:30","duration":8400},"12":{"start":1446488400,"stop":1446496800,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 19:20","stop_h":"02.11.2015, 21:40","duration":8400},"13":{"start":1446498600,"stop":1446513600,"start_h":"02.11.2015, 22:10","stop_h":"03.11.2015, 2:20","duration":15000}}
```

**EDIT_3 (SOLUTION)**

I found out!! It is because "this" is an Object inside ajax. jQuery and my Brain have caused that error. `console.log(this)` inside success of ajax pointed me in the right direction. I use the key name (`aufloesung.name` for example) to fill a new object. This only is taking place on the first load of the project so this would be ok. Please see comments inside the code.

Comment: And where are you reading the `window[target_object]`? Are you reading it before it is set?

Comment: i call download_datasave(aufloesung_history) for example. aufloesung_history is attached to Window as an empty Object only aufloesung.name is set as only element.

Comment: If the hardcode variable works, than the window object should have the same info. Seems like something is missing here that shows the real issue. Can you show the code how you call it and read it, not just a little piece?

Comment: added the function code, which creates the objects.

Comment: So now how does `download_datasave` come into play? And how do you read the data?

Comment: You said `console.log(response)` shows the expected object(s). Have you tested stripping out the AJAX stuff and just manually putting the object value(s) in `response` and then doing `window[target_object] = response`?

Comment: its more like objects inside object "thing".  see updated information above.

Answer (score 0):

Very unusual for me but i answer my own question. See commnet inside the ajax function.

```
function download_datasave (target_object) {
//  DOWNLOAD CALCULATION BACKUP
var filename, versuch = 0 ;

filename = target_object.name + '.json' ;

$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  url: datasave_hostname,
  timeout : 3000 ,
  data: {
    action : "download", target : filename, data : ""
    },
  success: function (data) {
      window[target_object.name] = JSON.parse(data) ;   // Works as ecxpected ;)
      window[target_object] = JSON.parse(data) ;   // does not work (dont know why). target_object is here an object with only one key in it (name)
      this[target_object.name] = JSON.parse(data) ;     // does not "work" because this isnt the DOMwindow Object
  },
  error : function (data) {
    console.log("Versuch : " + versuch + " fehlgeschlagen. Versuche es erneut.") ;

  }
});
```

};